# Is there any way to get this result order in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm helping a friend in his website but I'm actually stuck at this point.

His database was created by himself, who has no knowledge of database modelling, so I'm having a hard time getting the results I want from it.

I've got the following query which has everything that I need:

```
SELECT * FROM tabelaseriesbs 
    LEFT JOIN tabelatextosbs ON tabelatextosbs.nome = tabelaseriesbs.nome and tabelaseriesbs.alter_ego = tabelatextosbs.alter_ego and tabelatextosbs.versao = tabelaseriesbs.versao
    LEFT JOIN tabelaformatosbs ON tabelaformatosbs.colecao = tabelaseriesbs.colecao,
        (SELECT distinct tabelaseriesbs.nome, tabelaseriesbs.alter_ego, tabelaseriesbs.versao FROM tabelaseriesbs
        LEFT JOIN tabelaformatosbs ON tabelaformatosbs.colecao = tabelaseriesbs.colecao,
            (SELECT tabelaseriesbs.nome, tabelaseriesbs.alter_ego, tabelaseriesbs.versao FROM tabelaseriesbs 
                WHERE 1=1 AND (tabelaseriesbs.colecao = 'Universo Marvel') AND (tabelaseriesbs.raridade = 'Comum')
            ) col 
        WHERE 1=1 AND (col.nome = tabelaseriesbs.nome) AND (col.alter_ego = tabelaseriesbs.alter_ego) 
                  AND (col.versao = tabelaseriesbs.versao) AND (tabelaformatosbs.formato >= 2) 
         ) form 
    WHERE 1=1 AND (tabelaseriesbs.alter_ego = form.alter_ego) 
              AND (tabelaseriesbs.nome = form.nome) 
              AND (tabelaseriesbs.versao = form.versao) 
              AND (tabelatextosbs.sitiada_afiliacoes = '0') 
    ORDER BY tabelatextosbs.nome ASC, tabelatextosbs.alter_ego ASC, tabelatextosbs.versao ASC, cast(tabelaseriesbs.indice AS SIGNED) ASC;
```

which produces the following result

```
indice  nome       series
2       Hawkeye    Universo Marvel
4       Hawkeye    Poderes Ocultos
6       Hawkeye    Iniciativa Vingadores
8       Hawkeye    Battle Box
10      Hawkeye    Guerra Civil
1       Mercenary  Universo Marvel
3       Mercenary  Ascensão e Queda
5       Mercenary  Ascensão e Queda - Deck
```

But since the id of the first Mercenary is lower than the id of the first Hawkeye, those lines should have to appear before Hawkeye, like so:

```
indice  nome       series
1       Mercenary  Universo Marvel
3       Mercenary  Ascensão e Queda
5       Mercenary  Ascensão e Queda - Deck
2       Hawkeye    Universo Marvel
4       Hawkeye    Poderes Ocultos
6       Hawkeye    Iniciativa Vingadores
8       Hawkeye    Battle Box
10      Hawkeye    Guerra Civil
```

Is there a way to do that? Or do I have to do this in the code after getting the results? Also, there are a lot more fields than those 3, if you need the complete list, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin you query with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabelaseriesbs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT nome, MIN(cast(indice AS SIGNED)) as min_indice
    FROM tabelaseriesbs
    GROUP BY nome
) order_table USING (nome)
LEFT JOIN [...]
```

The subquery will find the least `indice` for every `nome`.

Then you can use `min_indice` in the ORDER BY clause

```
ORDER BY order_table.min_indice, [...]
```

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly. I've tried with group by before but couldn't get it to work, but using the inner join it was perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `tabelaseriesbs.id ASC` as an order by condition. This may disrupt your other order by conditions though depending on where you put it, but based on how I'm interpreting your query, putting this as your final condition should keep your other relative orders and order your ids as well.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot do mention, the id already is in the order by, but the query is in Portuguese. It's the last condition "cast(tabelaseriesbs.indice AS SIGNED) ASC"

Comment: @LucasHoffmann Why is it written id in the result set, if it's indice in the query? You should present us with real information, if you want real answers :)

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier Just edited the post so the tables reflect the actual names used in the query. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ORDER BY table.char DESC, table.id ASC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. What I need is to order by ID then get every other register that has the same name as the first and put those immediately after that, like:

2 - B
4 - B
6 - B
1 - A
3 - A
5 - A

Would turn into:

1 - A
3 - A
5 - A
2 - B
4 - B
6 - B

Since the lowest id is of a register "A".